# react-bootstrap, bsStyle is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[this is my react file[image: ][1]]I am a react developer, I am trying to use react-boostrap first time, I did npm install react-bootstrap, I put cdn in head in index.html, but I dont know bsStyle is not working, can anyone help me out with that. buttons should be in different colors. thank you

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Any error message?

Comment: Why do not you write more descriptive of the problem? Eg : Screenshot, Console Error, Code or Document etc.

Comment: I am so sorry for being not descriptive, there is no any error, but bsStyle is not changing my buttons.  I will try to make screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, there are multiple advantages of using input type as button, and it will solve your problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ButtonToolbar>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-default" value='Default'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Primary'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-success" value='Success'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-info" value='Info'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-warning" value='Warning'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-danger" value='Danger'/>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-link" value='Link'/>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: @hackrack jsut replace your buttontoolbar with my snippet  toolbar and it should make your life easy